# Fourier series of interpolating function result of NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, interpolation, series-expansion

I am having a tough time formulating the *right* question but here goes.

I know that solving the pde as in [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7141/204) gives me an interpolating function. I understand that the interpolating function object is different from the interpolating polynomial.

So if I wanted to approximate the interpolating function through `FourierSinSeries`, I don't quite get how I might go about it.

I can't just do:

`FourierSinSeries[InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,...},{0.,...},{0.,TMax}},<>],x,4]`

I tried that it didn't quite give me a series expansion.

## Edit:

Here's what I tried to do to get fourier coefficients describing my interpolating function.

### Mathematica code:

```
Off[NDSolve::ibcinc];
k=0.0677;
{xMin,xMax}={-(\[Pi]/k),\[Pi]/k};
TMax=2500;
uSol[t_,x_]=u[t,x]/.NDSolve[{\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\(u[t, x]\)\)==-100 \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x\)]\((
\*SuperscriptBox[\(u[t, x]\), \(3\)]\ 
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x, x, x\)]u[t, x])\)\)+1/3 \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x\)]\((
\*SuperscriptBox[\(u[t, x]\), \(3\)]\ 
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x\)]u[t, x])\)\)-5 \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x\)]\((
\*SuperscriptBox[\((
\*FractionBox[\(u[t, x]\), \(1 + u[t, x]\)])\), \(2\)]\ 
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x\)]u[t, x])\)\),u[0,x]==1-0.1 Cos[k x],
(*Piecewise Function for INITIAL CONDITION*)
(*u[0,x]== Piecewise[{{-0.1,-\[Pi]/k<= x<-\[Pi]/(10 k)},{ Cos[x],-\[Pi]/(10 k)<= x<= \[Pi]/(10 k)},{-0.1,\[Pi]/(10 k)<x<= \[Pi]/k}}],*)

(u^(0,1))[t,xMin]==0,
(u^(0,1))[t,xMax]==0,
(u^(0,3))[t,xMin]==0,
(u^(0,3))[t,xMax]==0

(*(u^(0,3))[t,xMin]==0,
(u^(0,3))[t,xMax]==0*)},
u,{t,0,TMax},{x,xMin,xMax},MaxStepSize->0.1,MaxSteps->100000,Method->{"BDF", "MaxDifferenceOrder"-> 5}][[1]]
```

### Fourier series:

Since I now have `uSol` which, my fourier coeffs should be:

```
I1 = NIntegrate[uSol[0.1 TMax, x], {x, xMin, xMax}] (*I1 at time=0.1 TMax*)
a0 = (1/(2*xMin))*I1
an = NIntegrate[uSol[0.1 TMax, x] Cos[n \[Pi] x/xMax], {x, xMin, xMax}]
bn = NIntegrate[uSol[0.1 TMax, x] Sin[n \[Pi] x/xMax], {x, xMin, xMax}]
```

Using `NIntegrate` errors out with:

```
NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand Cos[0.0677 n x] <<1>>[250.,x] has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{-46.4046,-46.3046}}. >>
```

However, using `Integrate` instead of `NIntegrate` gave me just the input as symbols.

Neither is the coefficient.

So what am I missing? There has to be a simpler way of figurijng out the fourier coeffs of an interpolating function.
can I export data out of mathematica into .csv or some other format which is not dependent on mathematica to be interpreted?

Comment: You might have to expand manually, using the definition for the Fourier coefficients (and thus `NIntegrate[]`).

Comment: @J.M. I am sorry but I don't entirely understand what that means. How do I go about expanding the `interpolating function` object manually? And why `NIntegrate[]`?

Comment: Something like `2 NIntegrate[f[t] Sin[n t], {t, 0, Pi}]/Pi` to generate your series coefficients, I meant.

Comment: @J.M. Ohhh! I see what you mean. Now it makes sense when you say, "use the definition of the fourier coefficients".... don't know why I didn't think of that!

Comment: you could also fourier sine transform the functions you're solving, end up with equations for the coefficients and solve those. but that is more work than what JM says.

Comment: @acl Goes to show how poor my math skills are! `:P`

Comment: @J.M. Added more details. Have failed miserably at getting the fourier coeffs.

Comment: Instead of `(u^(0,1))[t,xMin]`, maybe it's `Derivative[0,1][u][t,xMin]` what you want?

Comment: `NIntegrate` can't integrate symbolic arguments. You haven't fixed `n` so the integrand is not numerical; fix `n` to something and it should work. Unfortunately cut and pasting doesn't work for the reason @Silvia gave; if you fix that maybe we can help more easily.

Comment: also, isn't the question "suppose I have an interpolating function eg `fn = Interpolation[Table[{x, x^2}, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi], .1}]];` and I try to calculate the nth coefficient of the fourier cos series as `fn = Interpolation[Table[{x, x^2}, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi], .1}]];`; it gives such and such an error; what am I doing wrong?" there's no need for the `NDSolve` etc

Comment: @Silvia Aren't they both the same?

Comment: @DNA no, they are not the same at all. the `Derivative[0,1][u][t,xMin]` display like `(u^(0,1))[t,xMin]` just for 2-D display in a notebook frontend, it has different underlying structure for interpretation. Refer to the `InverseFunction` example in [this doc](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TagBox.html), please. Converting code to `InputForm` (Select the code, press ctrl+shift+i) before post it might be more convenient.

Comment: @Silvia Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Preliminary

First let me change the PDE that is being solve to make things go a bit faster:

```
k = 0.0677;
{xMin, xMax} = {-(\[Pi]/k), \[Pi]/k};
TMax = 100;
uSol[t_, x_] = u[t, x] /. NDSolve[{\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\(u[t, x]\)\) == (u[t, x] \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x, x\)]\(u[t, x]\)\)), 
     u[0, x] == 1 - 0.1 Cos[k x],
     Derivative[0, 1][u][t, xMin] == 0,
     Derivative[0, 1][u][t, xMax] == 0},
    u, {t, 0, TMax}, {x, xMin, xMax}, MaxStepSize -> 0.1][[1]]
```

## Answer

You want to calculate the nth coefficient, and try

```
an = NIntegrate[uSol[0.1 TMax, x] Cos[n \[Pi] x/xMax], {x, xMin, xMax}]
bn = NIntegrate[uSol[0.1 TMax, x] Sin[n \[Pi] x/xMax], {x, xMin, xMax}]
```

which fails with

```
NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand Cos[0.0677 n x] <<1>> [10.,x] has evaluated to
 non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries
  {{-46.4046,-46.3046}}.
```

This is literal and obviously true: `n` isn't fixed here. If I fix `n` it does give a result:

```
ClearAll[an, bn]
With[
 {n = 1},
 an = NIntegrate[
   uSol[0.1 TMax, x] Cos[n \[Pi] x/xMax], {x, xMin, xMax}];
 bn = NIntegrate[
   uSol[0.1 TMax, x] Sin[n \[Pi] x/xMax], {x, xMin, xMax}];
 ]
an
bn

(*
-4.43265
5.73641*10^-12
*)
```

(it also emits some warnings probably related to the fact that the $b_n$ actually is zero--although I could be wrong).

Anyway, I don't know if this is the best way to go about it, but this seems to work.

Comment: Yes, this probably works but I don't know yet know the physical significance of holding n constant. I'll have to think deep and hard about this.

Comment: What do you mean? You need n numerical to do the integral numerically, but you could do it for n=1, 2 etc. there's nothing deeper going on.

Comment: There might be something deeper going on as far as what n represents as far as harmonics being used as an input to simulate a very thin evaporating liquid film. But thank you!

Comment: I am not sure what deeper could be going on (or what you are trying to say), but OK :)