# EventLocator with LSODA?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, options

Is the `EventLocator` option not compatible with `LSODA` on `NDSolve`. Below is what I tried to do to arrest my simulation if the time step went below a certain value (based on [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7220/204) suggestion).

**The script file is also [attached](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/13223318/L_lambda_max_1wl_zg_E_0001_Cos_el).**

The error messages that I get are:

How should I go about it so that I can use `EventLocator` with `LSODA`.
The reason I am doing this is because my equation turns stiff and the last half of the time steps are extremely small, slow and unnecessary for me.

> ```
> NDSolve::moptx: Method option Method in {NDSolve`LSODA, 
> MaxDifferenceOrder -> 12, Method -> {EventLocator, Event :>
> If[stepsize < 10  , 0, 1]}}} is not one of {LinearSolveMethod,
> MaxDifferenceOrder}.
>
> NDSolve::initf: The initialization of the method NDSolve`LSODA failed.
> ```

```
#!/usr/local/bin/MathematicaScript -script

$HistoryLength=0;
$pwf=$InputFileName;
Needs["VectorAnalysis`"]
Needs["DifferentialEquations`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy`"];
Clear[Eq0,EvapThickFilm,h,Bo,\[Epsilon],K1,\[Delta],Bi,m,r]
Eq0[h_,{Bo_,\[Epsilon]_,K1_,\[Delta]_,Bi_,m_,r_}]:=\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]h\)+Div[-h^3 Bo Grad[h]+h^3 Grad[Laplacian[h]]+(\[Delta] h^3)/(Bi h+K1)^3 Grad[h]+m (h/(K1+Bi h))^2 Grad[h]]+\[Epsilon]/(Bi h+K1) + (r)D[D[(h^2/(K1+Bi h)),x] h^3,x] ==0;
SetCoordinates[Cartesian[x,y,z]];
EvapThickFilm[Bo_,\[Epsilon]_,K1_,\[Delta]_,Bi_,m_,r_]:=Eq0[h[x,y,t],{Bo,\[Epsilon],K1,\[Delta],Bi,m,r}];
TraditionalForm[EvapThickFilm[Bo,\[Epsilon],K1,\[Delta],Bi,m,r]];


L=79.5788; TMax=12500*100;
Off[NDSolve::mxsst];
Clear[Kvar];
Kvar[t_]:=  Piecewise[{{1,t<=1},{2,t>1}}]
(*Ktemp = Array[0.001+0.001#^2&,13]*)
hSol=h/.NDSolve[{
(*Bo,\[Epsilon],K1,\[Delta],Bi,m,r*)

EvapThickFilm[0,1*10^-6,1,0.001,1,2*0.025,0],
h[0,y,t]==h[L,y,t],
h[x,0,t]==h[x,L,t],
(*h[x,y,0] == 1.1+Cos[x] Sin[2y] *)
h[x,y,0]==1+(-0.05 Cos[2\[Pi] x/L] -0.05 Sin[2 \[Pi] x/L])(Cos[2\[Pi] y/L])
},
h,
{x, 0, L},
{y,0, L},
{t, 0, TMax},


StepMonitor :> (
       laststep = thisstep; thisstep = t; 
       stepsize = thisstep - laststep;
       ),


Method->{"LSODA","MaxDifferenceOrder"->12, Method -> {"EventLocator", 
         "Event" :> (If[stepsize < 10^-4, 0, 1])} },
MaxStepFraction->1/50,
PrecisionGoal->3
][[1]]




{TMin,TRup}=InterpolatingFunctionDomain[hSol][[3]];
hSolGridData=InterpolatingFunctionValuesOnGrid[hSol];
hSolCoords=InterpolatingFunctionCoordinates[hSol];
finalStep=InterpolatingFunctionCoordinates[hSol][[3]];
(*rupture=NumberForm[N[TRup/100],6];*)
rupture=TRup/100;

$parameterfile=StringJoin[$pwf,".dat"];
Export[$parameterfile, {0, 100, 0, 0.0001, 35.1, 7.02, 0, 3, 1, 5, SetPrecision[rupture,5]}];
$matfile=StringJoin[$pwf,".mat"];
Export[$matfile,hSolGridData];
(*Exports time step data*)
$timefile=StringJoin[$pwf,"_time",".mat"];
Export[$timefile,InterpolatingFunctionCoordinates[hSol][[3]]];

hGrid = InterpolatingFunctionGrid[hSol];
{TMin,TRup}=InterpolatingFunctionDomain[hSol][[3]];
Length[hGrid];
{nX,nY,nT}=Drop[Dimensions[hGrid],-1];

fac=0.98;


$epsfile0=StringJoin[$pwf,"_0",".eps"];
$pngfile0=StringJoin[$pwf,"_0",".png"];
$epsfileRup=StringJoin[$pwf,"_TRup",".eps"];
$pngfileRup=StringJoin[$pwf,"_TRup",".png"];
ic=Plot3D[hSol[x,y,0*TRup],{x,0,L},{y, 0, L},

PlotRange->{{0,L},{0,L},{0,3.5}},
BaseStyle->{FontWeight->"Plain",FontSize->18},
PlotPoints->65,
ColorFunction->GrayLevel
];
Export[$epsfile0,ic,ImageSize->{350,350}];
Export[$pngfile0,ic,ImageResolution->350];
rupProfile=Plot3D[hSol[x,y,fac*TRup],{x,0,L},{y, 0, L},

PlotRange->{{0,L},{0,L},{0,3.5}},
BaseStyle->{FontWeight->"Plain",FontSize->18},
PlotPoints->65,
ColorFunction->GrayLevel
];
Export[$epsfileRup,rupProfile,ImageSize->{350,350}];
Export[$pngfileRup,rupProfile,ImageResolution->350];

dataxy=Import[$matfile];
datat=Import[$timefile];


(*$epsfile0=StringJoin[$pwf,"_0_dft",".eps"];
$pngfile0=StringJoin[$pwf,"_0_dft",".png"];
$epsfileRup=StringJoin[$pwf,"_TRup_dft",".eps"];
$pngfileRup=StringJoin[$pwf,"_TRup_dft",".png"];
FDataFirst=Abs[Fourier[dataxy[[All,All,1]]]];
dftfirst=MatrixPlot[FDataFirst]*)
```

Comment: `"EventLocator"` is a *controller* method, while `"LSODA"` is an *integration* method. Witness for instance `NDSolve[{y''[x] == x y[x], y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0}, y, {x, -10, 0}, Method -> {"EventLocator", Method -> "LSODA", "Event" -> y'[x]}]`.

Comment: @J.M. Hmmm.. I didn't think that through.

Comment: @J.M. I have a further question: when you don't include the difference order, you aren't able to limit your differentiation to that order? I realize that since my difference order itself was set to 12, it wouldn't matter if I ommitted it.

Comment: You can still use the `"MaxDifferenceOrder"` option; replace `Method -> "LSODA"` in the snippet above with `Method -> {"LSODA", "MaxDifferenceOrder" -> 12}`. Yes, options can be nested in this case. The numerical solution of differential equations is a complicated affair, after all. ;)

Comment: BTW: ``NDSolve`LSODA // Options`` shows the defaults taken by the `"LSODA"` method value; as you can see, $12$ is indeed the maximum order taken by default.

Comment: @J.M. I tried `Method -> {"LSODA", "MaxDifferenceOrder" -> 12}` but it gave me a syntax error...

Comment: Really? `NDSolve[{y''[x] == x y[x], y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0}, y, {x, -10, 0}, Method -> {"EventLocator", Method -> {"LSODA", "MaxDifferenceOrder" -> 12}, "Event" -> y'[x]}]` works for me...

Comment: @J.M. I'll look into that again. Obv. going by your reputation, I might have a random inconspicuous key stroke.

Comment: @J.M. I have a question that is quite relevant to this topic: I am using the `EventLocator` method so as to stop my simulations when my equations' rather stiff demands need really small time steps. I am unsure if this is the right way to go about it. Right now I am running a case with stiff 4th order non lin PDE and it's taking several hours to finish. Any suggestions on how to either speed up the process or maybe "early stiffness detection"